# ODBC Teradata SQL Tool for OS X

Tags: sql, macos, teradata

TLDR; best Mac SQL Query solution for ODBC Teradata version 14 with some instructions on how to set it up.

Using ODBC version 14.x and Teradata DB version 14.x

Currently, running on a Windows 7 machine using Teradata SQL Assistant, though I am switching to a Mac and so far am unable to get OS X ODBC Management tool to function for my testing, nor could I get the download for the JE of SQL Assistant, as the site 404s. I tried Teradata Studio Express but it's not connecting to ODBC(it's using JDBC) and from what I am reading on the Teradata forums, there is no ODBC driver for Studio Express... with the SQL Assistant JE not available for download, I'm a lost on how I could be querying our Teradata Databases for testing on my Mac.

Others have suggested anything from Excel to Eclipse should work for SQL querying as long as I have the ODBC driver installed (i seem to), I made sure it was even version 14 as well as trying 15.

No dice... I think I am just too newb at this to figure it out without some guidance.

Thanks and if this post is not articulate enough kindly let me know what details I am leaving out and I can add them.

Thank you all so much!

Comment: JDBC will work on a Mac as well. In fact, most cross DBMS JDBC based SQL query tools should work on a Mac.

Comment: So JDBC can connect to an ODBC?

Comment: You don't connect "to ODBC", you connect to a database server using some kind of driver API. That driver can be ODBC or JDBC. Both driver talk directly to the database. If you use JDBC you don't need ODBC.

Comment: Sokath, his eyes uncovered! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Teradata Studio and Studio Express are the eventual replacement for SQL Assistant providing a cross platform IDE for Teradata professionals. Using it on your Mac should cause you no trouble other than the paradigm shift from using SQL Assistant to an Eclipse-based IDE.